How can I create a chart layout with multiple tickers in tradingview with Pine Script?
To get a general sense of the market I created a tradingview layout that comprises of BTCUSD pair, a particular ALTUSDT pair and the same ALTBTC pair. The issue is that I manually have to use the compare tool if I want to change the ALTUSDT pair and the corresponding ALTBTC pair. So is there a way I can automate it with Pine Script whereby it sync's the ALTUSDT and ALTBTC pairs as seen below?
Desired Template
So far I have been using the compare tool  to formulate my corresponding ALTBTC pairs. For example AVAXUSDT and AVAXBTC. I was expecting it to sync with the ALTUSDT chart but it doesn't. i.e Once I pick another ALTUSDT pair for example RUNEUSDT, the first pair AVAXUSDT changes while the ALTBTC pair, AVAXBTC still remains. Hence the layout will have RUNEUSDT and AVAXBTC which are not exactly comparable.
